# pass javaScript array together with form through jQuery ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

i am using ASP.NET MVC5 app. I have JavaScript array 'selectElementList' , holding multiple data and i am trying to post back data together with form value using AJAX JQuery function. In controller I get form value but getting null value for array... I believe I am missing something on view side.

### JavaScript Global Array

```
var selectElementList = [];   // I want to send this array to controller..
```

### JavaScript Add and confirm function

```
$("#ElementTable").on("click", ".k1-grid-confirm", function () {

        var E_RecordId = $(this).data("id");
        var E_MarkingSchemeTitle = $("#" + E_RecordId + "_EMST").val();
        var E_AvailableMark = $("#" + E_RecordId + "_AM").val();
        var E_PassMark = $("#" + E_RecordId + "_PM").val();
        var E_MeritMark = $("#" + E_RecordId + "_MM").val();
        var E_DistinctionMark = $("#" + E_RecordId + "_DM").val();

        //add data to array//

        selectElementList.push({ ElementIndex: E_RecordId, ElementMarkingSchemeTitle: E_MarkingSchemeTitle, ElementAvailableMark: E_AvailableMark, ElementPassMark: E_PassMark, ElementMeritMark: E_MeritMark, ElementDistinctionMark: E_DistinctionMark });   

        for (var i = 0; i <= selectElementList.length - 1; i++) {
            alert(selectElementList[i].ElementIndex + "  " + selectElementList[i].ElementMarkingSchemeTitle + " " + selectElementList[i].ElementAvailableMark + " " + selectElementList[i].ElementPassMark + " " + selectElementList[i].ElementMeritMark + " " + selectElementList[i].ElementDistinctionMark);
        }

});
```

### Submit function

```
 //QualificationElementsAndComponents ???????

 function submit_createNewQualification()
{

    //alert(JSON.stringify($("#NewQualificationForm").serializeObject()));

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/Qualification/CreateNewQualification",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",       
        data: JSON.stringify({ QualificationElementsAndComponents: selectElementList, newQualificationData: $("#NewQualificationForm").serializeObject() }),            
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == true) {
                window.location = "/Qualification/QualificationHome";
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });

}
```

### Controller Method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateNewQualification(QualificationViewModel newQualificationData, int [] QualificationElementsAndComponents)
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution, firstly I created mapping class of variables that I am expecting to pass to controller...

```
 public class QualificationElementComponents_ViewModel
{

    public int ElementIndex { get; set; }
    public string ElementMarkingSchemeTitle { get; set; }
    public int ElementAvailableMark { get; set; }
    public int ElementPassMark { get; set; }
    public int ElementMeritMark { get; set; }
    public int ElementDistinctionMark { get; set; }

    public IList<ElementComponent> _ElementComponent { get; set; }

}
```

then in controller method, pass above class reference as  parameter

```
 public ActionResult CreateNewQualification(QualificationViewModel newQualificationData, IList<QualificationElementComponents_ViewModel> ElementComponentList)
    {
       .......
```

and in View use ajax jquery to post data where data is JSON.stringify

```
   $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Qualification/CreateNewQualification",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ElementComponentList:selectElementList, newQualificationData: $("#NewQualificationForm").serializeObject() }),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == true) {
                         window.location = "/Qualification/QualificationHome";
                      }
                 },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    }
                });

    });
```

need to ensure variable names in JavaScript array and model class are same .... i.e. ElementComponentList